# determine if text field has focus or not

Tags: swift, if-statement, uipickerview

I am writing an if statement for an ios app and I want change the picker, based on which text field currently has focus.  here is what I have so far.

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    if (condition) {
        return array1.count
    }else{
        return array2.count
    }
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if (condition) {
        textBox1.text = array1[row]
    }else{
        textBox2.text = array2[row]
    }
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    if (condition) {
        return array1[row]
    }else{
       return array2[row]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `UITextField.isFirstResponder()`

Answer (score 0):

Well, while I dont see any code related to a textfield in your code, if we assume that you have an IBOutlet for a UITextfield named myTxt. This code for when it is touched:

```
myTxt.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CurrentViewController.MethodToUpdatePicker()), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

and this for when the value changes:

```
myTxt.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CurrentViewController.MethodToUpdatePicker()), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
```

Simply replace `CurrentViewController.MethodToUpdatePicker()` with your function to update the picker.

Here is more documentation from apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget:action:forControlEvents:

Comment: Sorry but I am still fairly new to using Swift.  I am not exactly sure where I am supposed to add those two lines of code or what function I am supposed to replace in there, since I have 4 different functions controlling my pickerview.